# Android - display ListView in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I've created an app that utilizes ListView and now I would like to display in a TabLayout, I've Googled this but none of the suggested solutions worked properly.

The tab layout itself is built as so:

**PageAdapter**

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            AllTasksTabFragment tab1 = new AllTasksTabFragment();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            WaitingTasksTabFragment tab2 = new WaitingTasksTabFragment();
            return tab2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

**AllTasksTabFragment**

```
public class AllTasksTabFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_tasks, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Main Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AllTasks tab layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/Main2ActivitylinearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/totalTask"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/Main2ActivitylinearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="Sort:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/sort_array"
        android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/Main2ActivitylinearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="No Tasks to Display"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/emptylist"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alltab_emptylist"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity OnCreate**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dbM = DBManager.getInstance(context);
    total_tasks_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTask);
    if(Globals.diffusr)
    {
        dbM.clearDB();
    }

    //check if any tasks exist in Parse DB
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Task");
    query.whereEqualTo("TeamName", Globals.team_name);

    if (Globals.IsManager == false) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        query.whereEqualTo("Employee", sharedpreferences.getString("LoginUsr", null));

        //if not manager disable action button
        FloatingActionButton fbtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fbtn.getLayoutParams();
        p.setBehavior(null); //should disable default animations
        p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID); //should let you set visibility
        fbtn.setLayoutParams(p);
        fbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    itemListAllTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    itemListWaitingTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    all_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alltasks_listView);
    waiting_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.waitingtasks_listView);

    try {
        tsks = query.find();
        for (ParseObject tmp : tsks) {
            tmp_task = new Task();
            tmp_task.setDescription(tmp.getString("Description"));

            int position = tmp.getInt("Category");
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tmp_task.setTask_catg(Category.GENERAL);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp_task.setTask_catg(Category.CLEANING);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp_task.setTask_catg(Category.ELECTRICITY);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmp_task.setTask_catg(Category.COMPUTERS);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tmp_task.setTask_catg(Category.OTHER);
                    break;
            }

            position = tmp.getInt("Priority");
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tmp_task.setPriority(Priority.LOW);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp_task.setPriority(Priority.NORMAL);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp_task.setPriority(Priority.URGENT);
                    break;
                default:
                    tmp_task.setPriority(Priority.NORMAL);
                    break;
            }

            position = tmp.getInt("Status");
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tmp_task.setTask_sts(Task_Status.WAITING);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp_task.setTask_sts(Task_Status.INPROGESS);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp_task.setTask_sts(Task_Status.DONE);
                    break;
                default:
                    tmp_task.setTask_sts(Task_Status.WAITING);
                    break;
            }

            position = tmp.getInt("Location");
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
                default:
                    tmp_task.setTsk_location(position);
                    break;
            }

            tmp_task.setDueDate(tmp.getDate("DueDate"));
            tmp_task.setParse_task_id(tmp.getObjectId());
            tmp_task.setEmp_name(tmp.getString("Employee"));
            syncTaskList(tmp_task);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }

    itemListAllTasks = dbM.getAllTasks();
    all_list.setAdapter(new TaskItemAdapter(context, itemListAllTasks));

    itemListWaitingTasks = dbM.getSortedTasks(Sorting.fromInteger(Sorting.WAITING.ordinal()));
    waiting_list.setAdapter(new TaskItemAdapter(context, itemListWaitingTasks));

    all_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {

            //get item instance from list
            Task tt = (Task) ((TaskItemAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

            if (Globals.IsManager == true) {
                Globals.temp = tt.getTsk_location();
                //start the create activity again, now for editing
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditTaskActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("task", tt);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TASK);
            }
            if (Globals.IsManager == false) {
                //start the create activity again, now for editing
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportTaskStatus.class);
                i.putExtra("task", tt);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_EMP_VIEW_TASK);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    waiting_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {

            //get item instance from list
            Task tt = (Task) ((TaskItemAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

            if (Globals.IsManager == true) {
                Globals.temp=tt.getTsk_location();
                //start the create activity again, now for editing
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditTaskActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("task", tt);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_TASK);
            }
            if (Globals.IsManager == false) {
                //start the create activity again, now for editing
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportTaskStatus.class);
                i.putExtra("task", tt);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_EMP_VIEW_TASK);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    all_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Long press to edit task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    waiting_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Long press to edit task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    emptylist_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alltab_emptylist);

    if (itemListAllTasks.size() == 0) {
        emptylist_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        total_tasks_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        emptylist_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        total_tasks_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        total_tasks_text.setText("");
        total_tasks_text.setText("Total " + itemListAllTasks.size());
    }
    sorts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sort_array);
    sort_selector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sortSpinner);
    sortSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sorts);
    sortSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sort_selector.setAdapter(sortSpinnerAdapter);

    sort_selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Globals.last_sort = position;
            SortTaskList(position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Spinner1:no selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("All Tasks"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Waiting"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

How should I do this when using tabs?
I have two tabs - AllTasks (which is displayed here) & Waiting (which is build in the same way).
How do I sent the ListView for each of them? So when a user transitions between tabs, the correct list will be displayed.

Comment: you can use 2 different fragments and a ViewPager.

Comment: so you want this itemList to be tranversed and dispalyed according to tab, let's say itmelist.get(0) for first tab? and itemList.get(1) second tab ?

Comment: @HourGlass, Do you have a code sample by chance?

Comment: yep, I can update here itself. So what are you actually trying to do ? are you trying to display listview by filtering,  "All Tasks" in All Task tab and waiting in waiting tab ?

Comment: @HourGlass, well I have two item lists, each Tab layout should display one of them. I initialize each item list & ListView in 'onCreate'.
I've updated the 'onCreate' method with my latest attempt.

Comment: you can use Hashmap to send two lists from activity to viewpager and then to fragment or you can use interface keep Hashmap in your activity and access same in each fragment. You can reuse the same fragment instead of creating everytime@DavidFaiz

Comment: Can I simplify this by creating a class with a single object - TaskList as public and place it there? and the fragment will access it from there?

Also, the usage of 'setOnItemLongClickListener' and the rest of the layout logic, such as the sorting function, should be placed in the 'Fragment' class or remain in the MainActivity?

Comment: @HourGlass, Can I simplify this by creating a class with a single object - TaskList as public and place it there? and the fragment will access it from there? Also, the usage of 'setOnItemLongClickListener' and the rest of the layout logic, such as the sorting function, should be placed in the 'Fragment' class or remain in the MainActivity?

Comment: you can do that also but you have to keep track of the position that your viewpager is in. so that every time your viewpager loads data it should load the data of the exact position. added an answer check it out. @DavidFaiz

Answer (score 1):

First Remove this listener from your activity code **tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener** . Then carry out like this.

**Interface:**

```
  public interface DavidInterface
    {
   List<Task> getListData(int position);
    }
```

**PageAdapter;**

```
  public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


          Fragment fragment = new yourOwnFragment();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putInt("position",position);
          fragment.setArguments(bundle);
          return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
```

**MainActivityOnCreate:**

```
class MainActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements DavidInterface

{
Hashmap<Integer,List<Task>> task_list_map = new HashMap<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    task_list_map.add(listitem1);
    task_list_map.add(listitem2);


}
//Interface method.  
@Override
public List<Task> getListData(int position)
{
    return task_list_map.get(position);

}
```

**TabFragment:**

```
public class AllTasksTabFragment extends Fragment
{   DavidInterface davidinterface;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_tasks, container, false);
      davidinterface = (DavidInterface)getActivity();
      Bundle bundle = getArguments();
      int pager_position = bundle.getInt("position",position);
      List<Task> task = davidinterface.getListData(pager_position);
     //populate this data in your listview inside this fragment layout. 

    }
}
```

Comment: In *PageAdapter*, you wrote 'yourOwnFragment', but I have two fragments, one 'AllTasksTabFragment' & 'WaitingTasksTabFragment', which of them should be placed there? or this means I only need one fragment? Sorry for the inconvenience, this is the first time I'm working with tabs.

Comment: Use only one fragment that's enough , so every time same fragment is loaded and data is retreived for that fragment using interface  or you can folllow you switch code but attach the bundle which I am sending with both fragment.

Comment: So both tabs are using the same fragment?

Comment: I get an error on:
      List<Task> task = davidinterface.getListData(pager_position);
It requests 'getListData' to be static....

Comment: @Override add this to top of the method in activity.

Comment: Added @Override in the main activity, where the method is implemented, still get the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106218/discussion-between-hourglass-and-david-faiz).

Comment: Can we chat again really quick?

Answer (score 0):

My fragment code
R.layout.second_fragment it's layout with listview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.times_listView);

    return v;
}
```